# C++ Beginner on using Sequences and Floating Points

Tags: c++, floating-point, points

How would you approach this exercise, as a beginning programmer? It is a classroom exercise, but I am truly trying to understand the best approach.

How far do you have to go in adding up a sequence of numbers for the sum to exceed 10000?
Print the last number added, and the final sum.

This is what I know to write for a simple adding code. Building off of this, how would you answer the above problem?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 
int main () 
{
int sum=0; 
int n;
for (n=1; n <250; n=n+1)
sum=sum+n;
cout<<"the sum of 1 through 250 is "<<sum<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this has something to do with floating-point arithmetics?

Comment: Can you explain better what your question is? Besides the 10 000 exceeding I don't see any other issues. For that: `for (int i = 1; i < 141; i++)`

Comment: izomorphius: I wasn't certain whether it was, but it was thrown out to me as a hint. As it turns out, a bad one ... but it was where I thought to start. Because I had a an unknown point that I was aiming for (one sum beyond 10000), it seemed to fit. That said, I am a beginner, and am still trying to piece together what rules apply where. Any advice to offer on floating-point arithmetics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to find the limiting values then perhaps this will help:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 
int main () 
{
int sum=0; 
int n=1;
while(sum<=10000){
sum=sum+n;
n++;
}
cout<<”to get 10000 you have to add till “<<n<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just add this condition (sum exceeds 10000) in your for() statement:

```
int sum=0;
for (int n=1; sum < 10000; n++)
    sum += n;

cout << "the sum of 1 through " << n-1 <<  " is " << sum << endl;
```

as soon as `sum >= 10000` the loop will stop and you have your answer. You can use while loop as well:

```
int sum=0, n = 0;
while (sum < 10000) {
    n++;
    sum += n;
}  
cout << "the sum of 1 through " << n <<  " is " << sum << endl;
```

or even

```
int sum=0, n = 0;
while ( (sum += ++n) < 10000 ) ;

cout << "the sum of 1 through " << n <<  " is " << sum << endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you want the sum of the sequence to be just more than 10000. So this is an AP (Arithmetic Progression). So we can implement the formula for the sum of a AP.

i.e. `S = n * [2a + (n-1)*d] / 2` 
check below link for details:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression

Put `a=1`, `d=1` and `S>10000` let us take `S=10000`
n we have to find out

the equation becomes
`n^2 + n - 20000 = 0`

which gives
`n = 141` (approximately taking the +ve value of sq. root)

Let n = X for an arbitrary problem. so we can run the following loop

sum = X * [2a + (X-1)d] / 2;

```
if(sum <= 10000)
   while(sum < 10000 && (++X))
      sum = X * [2a + (X-1)d] / 2;
else
   while(sum > 10000 && (--X))
      sum = X * [2a + (X-1)d] / 2;

cout << "We should continue the sequence up to" << X;
```

The above loop will take at most 3 iterations to find the X.

it will reduce the overhead of running a loop. e.g. if you have a bigger sum like instead of 10000 let it be 100000000 then you will get to see a huge difference in execution time.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Gaus's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_natural_numbers) to perform the reverse operation and skip the whole loop business. Then you would be using floats and sequences just as your title mentions.